# Scrapy returns all value in a single cell

Tags: python, scrapy

i'm trying to scrape this site using scrapy but returns all the value in a
 single cell, i except each value in a different row.

```
example:
milage: 25
milage: 377
milage: 247433
milage: 464130
```

but i'm getting the data like this

```
example:
milage:[u'25',
 u'377',
 u'247433',
 u'399109',
 u'464130',
 u'399631',
 u'435238',
 u'285000',
 u'287470',
 u'280000']
```

here is my code

```
import scrapy
from ..items import ExampleItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
url = 'https://example.com'
class Example(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = [url]
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item_selector = hxs.select('//div[@class="listing_format card5 relative"]')
        for fields in item_selector:
            item = ExampleItem()
            item ['Mileage'] = fields.select('//li[strong="Mileage"]/span/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make your [mcve] stand independent of your link to `commercialtrucktrader.com`.  Your question should be useful not just to you but to future readers as well, and we cannot trust that the link will remain available and relevant to your question in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: I didn't mean to change the link to `example.com`; I meant to add the relevant markup from the linked page into your question itself.

Comment: i think the ex: output data was good to understand what i'm asking.BTW i got the answer. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show your site but may be you need relative XPath:

```
item ['Mileage'] = fields.select('.//li[strong="Mileage"]/span/text()').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to iterate over your milages.

```
for fields in item_selector:
    milages = fields.select('//li[strong="Mileage"]/span/text()').extract()
    for milage in milages:
        item = CommercialtrucktraderItem()
        item ['Mileage'] = milage  
        yield item
```

Also consider making your `fields.select('//li[strong="Mileage"]/span/text()').extract()` more specific?

Comment: it's working but, is it possible to get the data directly from the first loop?

Comment: It sounds like the issue is that `fields.select('//li[strong="Mileage"]/span/text()').extract()` is matching many milages on one page. It sounds like if you're trying to match a listing, and there is one milage associated with it, you need to make your selector more specific to find that one milage.